# How to set virtualenv for a crontab?

Tags: python, cron, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I want to set up a crontab to run a Python script.

Say the script is something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "hello world"
```

Is there a way I could specify a virtualenv for that Python script to run in? In shell I'd just do:

```
~$ workon myenv
```

Is there something equivalent I could do in crontab to activate a virtualenv?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

If you're using "workon" you're actually using "virtualenv wrapper" which is another layer of abstraction that sits on top of virtualenv.  virtualenv alone can be activated by cd'ing to your virtualenv root directory and running:

```
source bin/activate
```

workon is a command provided by virtualenv wrapper, not virtualenv, and it does some additional stuff that is not necessarily required for plain virtualenv.  All you really need to do is source the bin/activate file in your virtualenv root directory to "activate" a virtualenv.

You can setup your crontab to invoke a bash script which does this:

```
#! /bin/bash    
cd my/virtual/env/root/dir
source bin/activate

# virtualenv is now active, which means your PATH has been modified.
# Don't try to run python from /usr/bin/python, just run "python" and
# let the PATH figure out which version to run (based on what your
# virtualenv has configured).

python myScript.py
```

Comment: Do I still need to use "#!/usr/bin/python" to specify my Python interpreter in my script? But my virtualenv might point to a different interpreter. This is where I'm confused.

Comment: You may want to take a look at what bin/activate is doing.  Activating a virtualenv is basically just modifying your PATH env var to point to specific versions of commands, like python, etc.  If you activate a virtualenv, then try to run /usr/bin/python, you may or may not be using the version of python that your virtualenv is expecting.  Rather than doing "#!/usr/bin/python" you can do "#!/usr/bin/env python" to let the env decide which python to run, based on your PATH.

Comment: Just as a heads up, don't try `source` in your cron line, as its a bashism and won't work since cron will use `/bin/sh` to execute your command.

Comment: make sure that the #! /bin/bash is the very first line in the file as well, no whitespace before it

Comment: It's not true to that all workon does is source the bin/activate file.  Virtualenvwrapper also has hooks you can use (e.g. postactivate) which won't be run if you just source the activate file.

Comment: Go with this script if using any custom email templates,custom paths, because checking would be very easy and it's scaleable

Comment: *"don't try source in your cron line, as its a bashism and won't work since cron will use /bin/sh to execute your command."* You can use `.` command in `sh` though. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150671/how-to-set-virtualenv-for-a-crontab/69037690#69037690

Answer (score 122):

> Is there something equivalent I could do in crontab to activate a virtualenv?

This works well for me...

```
## call virtualenv python from crontab
0    9    *    *    *    /path/to/virtenv/bin/python /path/to/your_cron_script.py
```

I prefer using python directly from the virtualenv *instead of hard-coding the virtualenv `$PATH` into the script's shebang*... or sourcing the venv `activate`

Comment: This works really well. In fact, it is also possible to put the absolute path to the python interpreter in the shebang (aka #!) of the script itself and, of course, make the script executable.

Comment: @AvinashMeetoo Yes, it's possible but this way it becomes location- and setup-dependan

Comment: Tried this, and found that my script couldn't import from other modules in the same project. Any ideas why that might happen?

Comment: @NathanGould you probably needed to add a `.pth` file in your virtual environment `virtual_env_folder/lib/python3.3/site-packages/app_name.pth` with the location of your app as directed here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10739838/1082673

Comment: `pyvenv-3.3` under Ubuntu 13.10 and Debian is buggy. See [bug 1093193](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.3/+bug/1093193) and [bug 1298831](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.3/+bug/1298831), and see the [reason and workaround](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=695758#20) (just add a symlink `venvdir/lib/python3.3/dist-packages` pointing to `site-packages`)

Comment: This is the better solution

Comment: What the heck is `0 9  * * * ` Can you explain that notation, i came to this post from anon crontab post.

Comment: @user1767754, see [`man 5 crontab`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab)

Answer (score 10):

With bash, you can create a generic virtual env wrapper that you can use to invoke ***any*** command, much like how [`time`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_time.htm) can wrapper any command.

## `virt_env_wrapper.bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash    
source path/to/virtual/env/bin/activate
"$@"
```

Bash's magical incantation `"$@"` re-escapes all tokens on the original command line so that if you were to invoke:

```
virt_env_wrapper.bash python foo.py bar 'baz blap'
```

`foo.py` would see a `sys.argv` of `['bar', 'baz blap']`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about `workon`, but it's pretty straightforward for `venv`. The only thing to remember is that `crontab` uses `sh` by default, not `bash`, so you need to use the `.` command instead of `source`.

Here are examples if you have a file `~/myproject/main.py`:

```
* * * * * cd ~/myproject && . .venv/bin/activate && python main.py > /tmp/out1 2>&1
```

You could also directly call the specific path of the `python` in the venv directory, then you don't need to call `activate`.

```
* * * * * ~/myproject/.venv/bin/python ~/myproject/main.py > /tmp/out2 2>&1
```

The downside of that is you would need to specify the project path twice, which makes maintenance trickier. To avoid that, you could use a shell variable so you only specify the project path once:

```
* * * * * project_dir=~/myproject ; $project_dir/.venv/bin/python $project_dir/main.py > /tmp/out3 2>&1
```