# Django: ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty

Tags: python, django, settings

I am trying to set up multiple setting files (development, production, ..) that include some base settings. Cannot succeed though. When I try to run `./manage.py runserver` I am getting the following error:

```
(cb)clime@den /srv/www/cb $ ./manage.py runserver
ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

Here is my settings module:

```
(cb)clime@den /srv/www/cb/cb/settings $ ll
total 24
-rw-rw-r--. 1 clime clime 8230 Oct  2 02:56 base.py
-rw-rw-r--. 1 clime clime  489 Oct  2 03:09 development.py
-rw-rw-r--. 1 clime clime   24 Oct  2 02:34 __init__.py
-rw-rw-r--. 1 clime clime  471 Oct  2 02:51 production.py
```

Base settings (contain SECRET_KEY):

```
(cb)clime@den /srv/www/cb/cb/settings $ cat base.py:
# Django base settings for cb project.

import django.conf.global_settings as defaults

DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False

INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1',)

ADMINS = (
    ('clime', 'clime7@gmail.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        #'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'cwu',                   # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'clime',                 # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Prague'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = False

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = False # TODO: make this true and accustom date time input

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = defaults.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS + ('%d %b %y', '%d %b, %y') # + ('25 Oct 13', '25 Oct, 13')

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = '/srv/www/cb/media'

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = '/srv/www/cb/static'

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '8lu*6g0lg)9z!ba+a$ehk)xt)x%rxgb$i1&amp;022shmi1jcgihb*'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.tz',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'web.context.inbox',
    'web.context.base',
    'web.context.main_search',
    'web.context.enums',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'watson.middleware.SearchContextMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'middleware.UserMemberMiddleware',
    'middleware.ProfilerMiddleware',
    'middleware.VaryOnAcceptMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'cb.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'cb.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    '/srv/www/cb/web/templates',
    '/srv/www/cb/templates',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'south',
    'grappelli', # must be before admin
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'endless_pagination',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'djangoratings',
    'watson',
    'web',
)

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'web.User'

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'null': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
        },
        'logfile': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': "/srv/www/cb/logs/application.log",
            'maxBytes': 50000,
            'backupCount': 2,
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
        'console':{
            'level':'INFO',
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers':['console'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'WARN',
        },
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'web': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'logfile'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    },
}

LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'logout'

#ENDLESS_PAGINATION_LOADING = """
#    <img src="/static/web/img/preloader.gif" alt="loading" style="margin:auto"/>
#"""
ENDLESS_PAGINATION_LOADING = """
    <div class="spinner small" style="margin:auto">
        <div class="block_1 spinner_block small"></div>
        <div class="block_2 spinner_block small"></div>
        <div class="block_3 spinner_block small"></div>
    </div>
"""

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    'INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS': False,
}

import django.template.loader
django.template.loader.add_to_builtins('web.templatetags.cb_tags')
django.template.loader.add_to_builtins('web.templatetags.tag_library')

WATSON_POSTGRESQL_SEARCH_CONFIG = 'public.english_nostop'
```

One of the setting files:

```
(cb)clime@den /srv/www/cb/cb/settings $ cat development.py 
from base import *

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '31.31.78.149']

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'cwu',
        'USER': 'clime',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

MEDIA_ROOT = '/srv/www/cb/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = '/srv/www/cb/static/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/srv/www/cb/web/templates',
    '/srv/www/cb/templates',
)
```

Code in `manage.py`:

```
(cb)clime@den /srv/www/cb $ cat manage.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "cb.settings.development")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

If I add `from base import *` into `/srv/www/cb/cb/settings/__init__.py` (which is otherwise empty), it magically starts to work but I don't understand why. Anyone could explain to me what's going on here? It must be some python module magic.

**EDIT:** Everything also starts to work if I remove this line from base.py

```
django.template.loader.add_to_builtins('web.templatetags.cb_tags')
```

If I remove this line from web.templatetags.cb_tags, it also starts to work:

```
from endless_pagination.templatetags import endless
```

I guess it is because, in the end, it leads to

```
from django.conf import settings
PER_PAGE = getattr(settings, 'ENDLESS_PAGINATION_PER_PAGE', 10)
```

So it creates some weird circular stuff and game over.

Comment: Exactly, in the end you will always need settings, even if it is from django.conf

Comment: Try changing your DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to settings.development

Comment: Anyone using virutalenvwrapper try crimeminister's answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738919/how-do-i-add-a-path-to-pythonpath-in-virtualenv-on-windows

Comment: If you use PyCharm or Wing IDE see answers below.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

I had the same error and it turned out to be a circular dependency between a module or class loaded by the settings and the settings module itself. In my case it was a middleware class which was named in the settings which itself tried to load the settings.

Comment: Ye, I think the circularity does it.

Comment: Do you know what the solution is then?

Comment: Refactor to avoid circular dependency. The exact solution is really fairly specific to your own code.

Comment: In my case as an example, I was calling  # django-admin.py runserver   that apparently imports the "settings.py" file in any of the directories included in the environment variable $PYTHONPATH and at the same time, in other environment variable $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE i had "settings" as content, that apparently means it will try to include "settings" as a module. So what I did to solve this was, emptying $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE with  # export $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Comment: Hint: in order to identify what's causing the issue, e.g. add a random print statement in the settings file and move it around to see where it breaks.

Comment: I didn't find an answer with this.

Comment: This must be why so many django features work on either **strings** or **objects**. That must have resolved tons of circular dependencies. (I got this error by importing in settings.py.)

Comment: Remove 'import haystack' from the top of your settings.py. 

Since you have django-haystack installed, it is already "available" to you. In the connection settings you can directly write haystack.backends... without explicitly importing it.

Comment: This answer would be more useful if it were more specific... it says the problem is "something".

Answer (score 95):

I ran into the same problem after restructuring the settings as per the instructions from Daniel Greenfield's book *Two scoops of Django*.

I resolved the issue by setting

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project_name.settings.local")
```

in `manage.py` and `wsgi.py`.

**Update:**

In the above solution, `local` is the file name (settings/local.py) inside my settings folder, which holds the settings for my local environment.

Another way to resolve this issue is to keep all your common settings inside settings/base.py and then create 3 separate settings files for your production, staging and dev environments.

Your settings folder will look like:

```
settings/
    __init__.py
    base.py
    local.py
    prod.py
    stage.py
```

and keep the following code in your `settings/__init__.py`

```
from .base import *

env_name = os.getenv('ENV_NAME', 'local')

if env_name == 'prod':
    from .prod import *
elif env_name == 'stage':
    from .stage import *
else:
    from .local import *
```

Comment: For anyone using Wagtail on PythonAnywhere just add the '.dev.' at the end of this line in WSGI ... os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings.dev' later you'll need to create a local.py outside of your source repo for your passwords etc.

Comment: Should be top answer

Comment: ImportError: No module named local

Comment: @Tessaracter use the name of the settings file you use instead of `local`. In my case, the local settings were kept in the file settings/local.py

Comment: This violates Django conventions, replacing the properly documented `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` with a new custom environment variable that is not supported out of the box and has to be dealt with manually. I am surprised this has so many upvotes. I'm working on a project with this setup and we're running into a lot of problems, from difficulties in configuring an isolated environment for local development to external libraries breaking because they expect the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to work as expected and it doesn't.

Answer (score 23):

I had the same error with `python manage.py runserver`.

For me, it turned out that it was because of a stale compiled binary (.pyc) file. After deleting all such files in my project, server started running again. :)

So if you get this error, out of nowhere, i.e without making any change seemingly-related to django-settings, this could be a good first measure.

Comment: thanks for this tip. I had an identical issue on my dev server. Deleting all .pyc files from the project folder did the trick. I was editing the settings.py file just prior to this happening.

Answer (score 18):

**Remove .pyc files**

**Ubuntu terminal command for deleting .pyc :**
`find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -rf {} \;`

I have got same error when I did python manage.py runserver. It was because .pyc file. I deleted .pyc file from project directory then it was working.

Comment: `find . -type f -name  *.pyc  -delete` will do

Answer (score 16):

I hadn't specified the settings file:

```
python manage.py runserver --settings=my_project.settings.develop
```

Answer (score 8):

It starts working because on the base.py you have all information needed in a basic settings file. You need the line:

```
SECRET_KEY = '8lu*6g0lg)9z!ba+a$ehk)xt)x%rxgb$i1&amp;022shmi1jcgihb*'
```

So it works and when you do `from base import *`, it imports SECRET_KEY into your `development.py`.

You should always import basic settings before doing any custom settings.

---

EDIT:
Also, when django imports development from your package, it initializes all variables inside base since you defined `from base import *` inside `__init__.py`

Comment: sorry, I don't get your point. There was from base import * in at the beginning of development.py and it did not work.

Comment: Oh sorry, I've jumped in regardless what was really happening. Django is still trying to import settings from settings instead of your development.py as it seems the reason of working when you import base at __init__.py

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem with Celery. My setting.py *before*:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY')
```

after:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY', <YOUR developing key>)
```

If the environment variables are not defined then: SECRET_KEY = ***YOUR developing key***

Answer (score 7):

I think that it is the **Environment error**,you should try setting : `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='correctly_settings'`

Answer (score 6):

for development just update settings.py, and should work

```
SECRET_KEY = '*'
```

Answer (score 5):

For anyone using PyCharm: the green "Run selected configuration" button would produce this error, yet running the following works:

`py manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000 --settings=app_name.settings.development`

To fix this you need to edit the configuration's environment variables. To do this click the "Select run/debug configuration" drop-down menu to the left of the green run button and then click on "edit configuration". Under the "environment" tab change the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to `app_name.settings.development`.

Answer (score 4):

In the **init**.py of the settings directory write the correct import, like:

```
from Project.settings.base import *
```

No need to change wsgi.py or manage.py

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem occurring on OS X with Django both 1.5 and 1.6 by deactivating all active sessions to virtualenv and starting it again.

Answer (score 2):

To throw another potential solution into the mix, I had a `settings` folder as well as a `settings.py` in my project dir. (I was switching back from environment-based settings files to one file. I have since reconsidered.)

Python was getting confused about whether I wanted to import `project/settings.py` or `project/settings/__init__.py`. I removed the `settings` dir and everything now works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add that I got this error when my database name was spelled wrong in my `settings.py` file so the DB couldn't be created.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem on 1.8.4 by fixing the TEMPLATES settings which had a typo (removing TEMPLATES['debug'] solved it)

Go over the settings that you have changed recently, make sure all keys are by-the-book.

Answer (score 1):

My Mac OS didn't like that it didn't find the env variable set in the settings file:

```
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('MY_SERVER_ENV_VAR_NAME')
```

but after adding the env var to my local Mac OS dev environment, the error disappeared:

```
export MY_SERVER_ENV_VAR_NAME ='fake dev security key that is longer than 50 characters.'
```

In my case, I also needed to add the `--settings` param:

```
python3 manage.py check --deploy --settings myappname.settings.production
```

where production.py is a file containing production specific settings inside a settings folder.

Answer (score 1):

The issue for me was calling `get_text_noop` in the LANGUAGES iterable.

Changing

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en-gb', get_text_noop('British English')),
    ('fr', get_text_noop('French')),
)
```

to

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en-gb', _('British English')),
    ('fr', _('French')),
)
```

in the base settings file resolved the `ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty` exception.

Comment: I've got same issue. Need to change
> from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

to:
> from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

Answer (score 1):

The reason why there are so many different answers is because the exception probably doesn't have anything to do with the SECRET_KEY.
It is probably an earlier exception that is being swallowed. 
Turn on debugging using DEBUG=True to see the real exception.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was because I was trying to setup [`django-environ`](https://dev.to/joshwizzy/how-to-keep-secrets-out-of-django-settings-41c4) and I missed an important step:

> Note: In the instructions below .env.example and .env should be saved in the same folder as settings.py

I incorrectly assumed that `.env` belonged in the root of my project. Moving it to the same folder as `settings.py` fixed the problem.

This error message in the Python console was the clue that set me on the right path:

```sh
Warning: /Users/allen/PycharmProjects/myapp/myapp/.env doesn't exist - if you're not configuring your environment separately, create one.
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by removing the spaces around equal signs (`=`) in my `.env` file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was - I had my `app_folder` and `settings.py` in it. Then I decided to make `Settings folder` inside `app_folder` - and that made a collision with `settings.py`. Just renamed that `Settings folder` - and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above problem by commenting the line in my settings.py

```
SECRET_KEY=os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
```

`SECRET_KEY` declared in my `~/.bashrc` file(for linux Ubuntu users)

For development purpose on my localmachine I did not use evironmnet variable

```
SECRET_KEY = '(i9b4aes#h1)m3h_8jh^duxrdh$4pu8-q5vkba2yf$ptd1lev_'
```

above line didn't give the error

Answer (score 0):

In my case, while setting up a Github action I just forgot to add the env variables to the yml file:

```
jobs:
  build:
    env:
     VAR1: 1
     VAR2: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after a long search I found that PyCharm in your Django settings (Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Django) had the configuration file field undefined. You should make this field point to your project's settings file. Then, you must open the Run / Debug settings and remove the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = existing path.

This happens because the Django plugin in PyCharm forces the configuration of the framework. So there is no point in configuring any os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myapp.settings')

Answer (score 0):

> Import base.py in `__init__.py`  alone. make sure you won't repeat the same configuration again!.
>
> set environment variable
> `SET DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT =dev`

```
settings/
  __init__.py
  base.py
  local.py
  production.py
```

> In  `__init__.py`

```
from .base import *
if os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT')=='prod':
   from .production import *
else:
   from .local import *
```

> In `base.py` configured the global configurations. except for Database. like

```
SECRET_KEY, ALLOWED_HOSTS,INSTALLED_APPS,MIDDLEWARE .. etc....
```

> In `local.py`

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'database',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432',
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for answer as I was facing the same issues, none of the answers here worked for me. Then after searching in other websites i stumbled upon this simple fix. It worked for me

wsgi.py

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'yourProject.settings')
```

to

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'yourProject.settings.dev')
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me share m interesting solution!

I put the
SECRET_KEY = "***&^%$#" in settings packages **init**.py file and the error disappeared! it's actually a loading problem!

Hope this quick workaround is useful for some of you!

Answer (score 0):

try import django then run django.setup() after the secret_key definition. like so:

```
SECRET_KEY = 'it5bs))q6toz-1gwf(+j+f9@rd8%_-0nx)p-2!egr*y1o51=45XXCV'
django.setup()
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using **Wing IDE**: set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in your project properties to `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=${DJANGO_SITENAME}.config.settings.development`

You will find the settings under: **Project** --> **Project Properties** and set the value in the field **Environment**

Answer (score 0):

(I am using Pycharm, I also tried every solution in here and found out that the solutions works on some codes and some doesn't so I just did this solution)

The easiest Resolution that I did is I deleted the LIB where the installed sitepackages are, opened python interpreter in the settings and then it gave me an option where the program(Pycharm) installed the pip/sitepackges and I reinstalled the rest of the packges for example rest_framewrok etc. in the virtual environment of the project using cmd(or any command prompt tool) and it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used a web service to generate a random key: https://djecrety.ir/

It had multiple dollar signs in it and ruined my manage.py runs. Pycharm's Run Configuration worked fine with it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case nothing worked because I `source`-ed `.env` file. I was able to see the values of the variable with `echo $SECRET_KEY` but python process didn't see it. This happens because it isn't exported, so I had to export all values with the following command:

```
eval $(egrep -v '^(#|$)' .env | sed 's|^|export |')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Django 3.0 , the `AdminEmailHandler` logging handler can raise this, since it tries to read the default `reporter_class` from settings - which creates a kind of circular dependency issue.

A solution is to set the `reporter_class` in the config of the handler:

```
"mail_admins": {
    "level": "ERROR",
    "class": "django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler",
    "reporter_class": "django.views.debug.ExceptionReporter",                                              
},
```

Source: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32016#comment:9