# Different settings.py for each virtual environment in a project

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I have a project in where exist two virtual environments such as follow:

- `(env_dev)` for development
- `(env_test)` for testing

I want perform in these two virtual environments different configurations.
In my testing environment would go libraries or packets (like selenium), that possibly don't will be needed in the development environment and so...

According to above mentioned I have the following directory structure in relation to the requirements files and settings files of this way:

**Requirements files (root_project/requirements)**

I have the files:

- root_project/requirements/base.txt in where will be all packages that are commons to all environments. The other requirements files will inherit of it
- root_project/requirements/development.txt, just the packages needed for the development local environment
- root_project/requirements/production.txt, just the packages for the production environment
- root_project/requirements/testing.txt, just the packages needed for the testing environment
- root_project/requirements/staging.txt, packages for the staging environment just in case

In addition, after that I've write the packages in each requirements file, 
I proceed to install the packages in the testing and development environments of this way:

```
$ workon env_dev
$ pip install -r requirements/development.txt

$ workon env_test
$ pip install -r requirements/testing.txt
```

**Differents settings for each virtual environment (testing and development)**

Then, I proceed to create the settings folder inside my root_project folder for manage different  settings files por each environment

**root_project/settings** will have:

`__init__.py` file to make this folder a Python package

`base.py` will contain all the settings that are common in all environments. The other setting files inherit from this one.

`development.py` is for local development.

`testing.py` is for testing.

`production.py` will be used in the production environment.

`staging.py` just in case of run a staging version on the production server of my project.

The files `__init__.py` , `development.py` , `testing.py` , `production.py` and `staging.py` , I have edited with these lines for that  inherit from base.py (which still don't create):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from .base import *
```

And, in my root_project/name_project/ django create by default the `settings.py` file. 
This file, I've moved to root_project/settings directory and I've renamed to base.py, because this file settings.py will be my base.py

With virtualenvwrapper, I specify that file will work with a virtual environment specific:

`env_test` will work with testing with testing.py

`env_dev` will work with development.py

In each path [$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin] of each virtual environment (testing and development) I configure this files (development.py and settings.py) to use, focus me in the postactivate file and predeactivate file such as follow

**In env_dev environment**

Go to `$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin` path and I edit the postactivate file adding:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="taskbuster.settings.development"
```

And I also go to `$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin` path and I edit the predeactivate file adding:

```
unset DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
```

**In env_test environment**

Go to `$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin` path and I edit the postactivate file adding:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="taskbuster.settings.testing"
```

I've just adding in postactivate file, not in predeactivate.

When I want check if all this process works, activating the env_dev environment I get this output

```
(env_dev)➜  taskbuster_project  ./manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/tb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/tb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/tb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/tb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/tb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/tb_dev/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2231, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2189, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2231, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2201, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'taskbuster.settings'
(env_dev)➜  taskbuster_project
```

With my env_test environment occur the same situation
Can I have some error configuration.

Excuse me to everyone for the amount of lines in this question.
As an additional data all this process I have been doing based in this full complete tutorial http://www.marinamele.com/taskbuster-django-tutorial/settings-different-environments-version-control just in case.

Thanks. 
Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

You have set `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="taskbuster.settings.testing"`, but above you say the settings sit under `root_project/settings`. So, if I understand your setup correctly, you need to move the settings directory under one called `taskbuster`.

Of course, the quicker alternative is to change the env var to `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="settings.testing"`

It depends on what you desire in terms of directory structure.

Comment: I've moved under taskbuster project and now I get this message: (tb_dev)➜  taskbuster_project  python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/tb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 113, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
(tb_dev)➜  taskbuster_project

Comment: I have looking this post but I don't understand my specific case  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128540/django-improperlyconfigured-the-secret-key-setting-must-not-be-empty and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29455057/django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-the-secret-key-setting-must-not-be

Comment: I follow the recommendation in this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128540/django-improperlyconfigured-the-secret-key-setting-must-not-be-empty) of add from .base import in the taskbuster/settings/__init__.py (this file was empty) and all works  and I also understand why? Anyone could explain to me what is going here too? Thanks

Comment: if your SECRET_KEY comes from an env variable, make sure you set it (export it). And when you change such vars, always remember to re-source the file where you set the variables (e.g. ~/.bashrc) and/or deactivate-reactivate the venv in your case.

Answer (score 0):

After editing the postactivate and predeactivate you have to reactivate the environment.
When you are in env_dev, you can either do:

```
$workon env_test   //change to another env and come back
$Workon env_dev
```

OR

```
$deactivate  //just deactivate and activate the concerned env
$workon env_dev
```

This should work.