# How to get Uwsgi working with wagtail (django)

Tags: python, django, uwsgi, wagtail

I am trying to get up to speed with wagtail. I am running it on a remote server. I have installed a virtual environment, then I switched to the virtual environment and installed wagtail as per the steps here: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/getting_started/tutorial.html

1. `pip install wagtail`
2. `wagtail start rocker`
3. `cd rocker`
4. `pip install -r requirements.txt`
5. `python manage.py migrate`
6. `python manage.py createsuperuser`

The next step in the guide is to test the installation has worked by running:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I can't do this as working with a remote server, and also there is already a Django app running on the server (using uwsgi).

So I am now trying to connect to this wagtail app, via uwsgi.

Using the string that starts the existing app as a template, I have modified it to bind a socket to the wagtail app: -

```
uwsgi --chdir=/opt/rocker/rocker --module=rocker.wsgi:application --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=rocker.settings --master --pidfile=/tmp/rocker.pid --socket=/opt/rocker/core.sock --processes=5 --uid=www-data --gid=www-data --harakiri=20 --max-requests=5000 --vacuum --home=/opt/rocker --daemonize=/var/log/uwsgi/rocker.logroot@caspium:/etc/init.d#
```

However the app isn't starting... the error in the uwsgi log says the following: -

```
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./rocker/wsgi.py", line 18, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/opt/rocker/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/opt/rocker/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/opt/rocker/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/opt/rocker/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/opt/rocker/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 116, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
**django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.**
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 4617)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 4622, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 4623, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 4624, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 4625, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 5 (pid: 4626, cores: 1)
```

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting
>   must not be empty.

I researched this and found this [Django: ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128540/django-improperlyconfigured-the-secret-key-setting-must-not-be-empty) which suggests adding

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project_name.settings.local")
```

in `manage.py` which I did. This did not fix anything.

I also found this [django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29455057/django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-the-secret-key-setting-must-not-be) which says you need a secret key specified in `settings.py`

However in the wagtail project there is no settings.py

I created one and added a secret key, and am still getting the error.

Can someone advise how I can fix this so I can run uwsgi to connect to the wagtail, and test if it's working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the following file:

```
/opt/rocker/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/global_settings.py
```

There is a `Secret Key = ''` specified here.

I added a secret key, and the app ran ok with Uwsgi

Comment: You added it there ? in the virtualenvs directly ?

Comment: This solution works fine but it's not the right way. Django should automatically pick the SECRET_KEY with the one provided by local,base,production,dev...py as all the other django apps do. Wagtail is complicating things.

Answer (score 2):

In the Wagtail base project structure, `settings.py` is split into several files in the `settings` directory - see http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/reference/project_template.html#django-settings for details. The best place to put `SECRET_KEY` is `settings/local.py`, since you want to keep it out of version control.

Comment: Thank you gasman, I'd be lost without your help. I just created a file called local.py in the settings folder (as there was no local.py already ; however there was a dev.py, production.py, and base.py) and simply placed this line at the top of it: " SECRET_KEY = '123' " without the speech marks. I ran Uwsgi again, and received the same error. Do i need to run any migrate commands or any such like thing, do you think? to make these changes take effect?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me after so many tries, was to delete the whole `settings/` folder and create a proper `settings.py` file instead. If you guys from @Wagtail want to separate settings... you can do this https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/11/01/django-tip-19-protecting-sensitive-information.html