# Wrong settings module in Django

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I have made the following directory structure:

```
project
    main_app
        settings
            base.py
            local.py
            production.py
    ...
    manage.py
```

I started `local.py` with:

```
from .base import *
```

I update `manage.py` as follows (mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23492368/1469465)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings.local")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Running my unit tests works. I run the server locally, which works. Making calls to the API works. I then call a script, in which I have the following:

```
from django.conf import settings

data_dir = Path(settings.BASE_DIR) / 'csv'
```

When I run this script however, I get the following error upon loading the object `settings`:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

When I print the settings module in class `Settings in django/conf/__init__.py`, I see that it takes the wrong settings file (which does not exist):

```
class Settings(BaseSettings):
    ...
    print('Settings module: {}'.format(settings_module))
    print('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: {}'.format(os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']))

Settings module: project.settings
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: project.settings
```

Why doesn't it take the correct settings file, as indicated in `manage.py`? I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20646241/1469465) that it might be a circular reference in middleware, but I can't find it. This is my middleware setting:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
]
```

When I echo the environment variable `$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in a shell, I get an empty line back. To check if the environment variable is set somewhere in my project, I search for it explicitly in the terminal.

```
$ pwd
/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/project/src
$ sift DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
Binary file matches: project/__pycache__/wsgi.cpython-35.pyc
main_app/wsgi.py:os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "main_app.settings.local")
Binary file matches: fe_import/__pycache__/CsvReader.cpython-35.pyc
fe_import/CsvReader.py:    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "main_app.settings.local") ==> This is the script I am running
manage.py:    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "main_app.settings.local")
```

Comment: Can you `echo $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in your shell? If it's set, it will override the default set in your `manage.py`. Could you also paste the full content of your updated `manage.py` script?

Comment: I have updated the question with this additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Running my unit tests works. I run the server locally, which works. Making calls to the API works. **I then call a script, in which I have the following:**

How do you call your script? Clearly not via `manage.py`.

This line:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings.local")
```

needs to appear in every script.

Also, be sure that there is nothing around that is overriding the value for `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`, and nothing that is manually calling `settings.configure()`.

---

**Tip:** to avoid repeating the same code over and over again, and to avoid problems of this kind, I often use [custom management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/) instead of writing my own scripts.

Comment: Indeed I was not running it through `manage.py`. I now copied that line into my script before loading the settings object. However, I still get the same error.

Comment: @physicalattraction: in `conf/__init__.py`, other than printing the settings module name, try printing the value for `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`. Also, be sure not to call `settings.configure()` (and not to call `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` twice)

Comment: The environment variable is set to the same as the settings module name, I have updated that now in the question. I (think I) am not explicitly calling `settings.configure()` or `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` twice, unless that is what happens with the line `from django.conf import settings`.

Comment: @physicalattraction: somewhere, something is overriding the env var. Try `grep -r DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` and be sure that `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is really unset when you call your script (remember, `setdefault()` works only if the env var is not set)

Comment: Indeed, the environment variable is set already! I am running it automatically in Eclipse. When I set the environment variable instead of using `setdefault`, the problem disappears! :-)

Comment: @physicalattraction: you should tell Eclipse not to set the variable. Avoiding `setdefault()` is not a solution: if you do so you won't be able to set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings.production` from the command line!

Comment: Do you happen to know how to do this? In the Run Configuration, in the tab Environment, everything is empty already.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it helps, but i will tell what i know and how we do this. First of all its a bad idea to patch manage.py. I believe this file need to be untouched. We have following setup: one settings.py contains settings and variables for project. Near it we have local.py. and in the settings we have: `import * from local`. this file lives on a local machine and have something like this:

```
#database settings for sqlite
#passwords for apis
debug=True
```

then we have to add this file to .gitignore so after git pull from production we wont be have this file on production server. 
On production we create another local.py

```
#database settings for production database
#passwords for apis
debug=False
```

So local is mean not development but "local for this machine"

Comment: I am following the convention from the book Two Scoops of Django, which to be honest seems to be a better way of handling different settings files.

Comment: It's entirely valid to patch `manage.py` to suit your needs. It's part of your project, not your Django installation.