# SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty

Tags: python, django

I am getting Error when i run server in cmd

I am using Windows 7, Python Version 3.4.3 and
Django Version 1.8.

```
> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute_f
rom_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 190, in fetch_com
mand
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 40, in load_comma
nd_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 14, in
<module>
    from django.db.migrations.executor import MigrationExecutor
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .loader import MigrationLoader
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 9, in <module>
    class MigrationRecorder(object):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 23, in MigrationRec
order
    class Migration(models.Model):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 24, in Migration
    app = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1081, in __init_
_
    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 161, in __init__

    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\myapp\myapp\settings.py", line 16, in <module>
    import django.contrib.auth
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.middleware.csrf import rotate_token
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\csrf.py", line 14, in <module>
    from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\cache.py", line 26, in <module>
    from django.core.cache import caches
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\cache\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    if DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS not in settings.CACHES:
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 113, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

Comment: Please post your `settings.py` file contents. Secret key seems to be missing

Comment: I can't post settings.py file contents

Comment: Which part of the error message is unclear exactly?..

Comment: 1) What is the exact command that you are trying to run? 2) What is the value of the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable? 3) Is your secret key well defined in your settings.py file?

Comment: I think its becouse of django and python incompatibilty

Comment: 1) I am writting --> python manage.py runserver. 2) where i can find DJSNGO_SETTING_MODULE environment variable?  3) there is a secret key in settings.py file

Comment: what directory are you running this command in?

Comment: `python manage.py runserver --settings project_name.settings`
`project_name.settings` = path from you project to your settings file.

Comment: in Project's directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET\_KEY setting must not be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128540/django-improperlyconfigured-the-secret-key-setting-must-not-be-empty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was Django version incompatibility issue. When I installed 1.5 version and 1.9 version of django it is working but not with 1.10 and 1.8

Answer (score 1):

If SECRET_KEY is in setttings.py file then you are running different settings file.

use below command:

```
python manage.py runserver --settings project_name.settings
```

`project_name.settings` is path to your settings file.

You can also check it using `print` statements in settings.py file

Answer (score -4):

I think the error message is pretty much self-explaining:
`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.`

You need to set SECRET_KEY in your settings.py file.

Comment: It's in settings.py file--->   SECRET_KEY = '*1_(=mc+3q&=%4n$h1)v!zwrl-n+pr-s#xfpd##!l+ek4&x‌​y2x'

Comment: So the `SECRET_KEY` is already set? Maybe you use different settings.py file that you think.
Could you add ipdb or print to you settings.py file to check if it is really loaded?