# Error: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty

Tags: django, mongodb, django-rest-framework

I have seen many other answers but nothing helped.

Things I have tried,

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app_name.settings")
```

In both manage.py and wsgi.py file.

There is a secret key, in the settings file, but still it shows this.

I also tried,

```
$ export SECRET_KEY='value of secret key'
```

And also,

```
import django 
django.setup()
```

There is **init.py** file there also. I don't know what is the issue. Please help.

I am using mongodb as database backend, and it is giving me this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/luvpreet/.virtualenvs/mongo3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/luvpreet/.virtualenvs/mongo3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 342, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/luvpreet/.virtualenvs/mongo3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 195, in fetch_command
klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
File "/home/luvpreet/.virtualenvs/mongo3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 39, in load_command_class
module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/home/luvpreet/.virtualenvs/mongo3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 16, in <module>
from django.db.migrations.executor import MigrationExecutor
File "/home/luvpreet/.virtualenvs/mongo3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 7, in <module>
from .loader import MigrationLoader
File "/home/luvpreet/.virtualenvs/mongo3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 10, in <module>
from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder
File "/home/luvpreet/.virtualenvs/mongo3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 12, in <module>
class MigrationRecorder(object):
File "/home/luvpreet/.virtualenvs/mongo3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 26, in MigrationRecorder
class Migration(models.Model):
File "/home/luvpreet/.virtualenvs/mongo3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 27, in Migration
app = models.CharField(max_length=255)
File "/home/luvpreet/.virtualenvs/mongo3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1072, in __init__
super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/luvpreet/.virtualenvs/mongo3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 166, in __init__
self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
File "/home/luvpreet/.virtualenvs/mongo3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "/home/luvpreet/.virtualenvs/mongo3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "/home/luvpreet/.virtualenvs/mongo3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/home/luvpreet/Desktop/drf-vogo/new_mongo/new_mongo/settings.py", line 16, in <module>
django.setup()
File "/home/luvpreet/.virtualenvs/mongo3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
File "/home/luvpreet/.virtualenvs/mongo3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "/home/luvpreet/.virtualenvs/mongo3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "/home/luvpreet/.virtualenvs/mongo3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 120, in __init__
raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
```

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.

UPDATED BELOW-

Here,

```
(mongo3) luvpreet@DHARI-Inspiron-3542:~/Desktop/drf-vogo/new_mongo$ pip freeze
Django==1.9
django-rest-framework-mongoengine==3.3.1
djangorestframework==3.3.3
mongoengine==0.9.0
pymongo==2.7
```

Stacktrace,

```
(mongo3) luvpreet@DHARI-Inspiron-3542:~/Desktop/drf-vogo/new_mongo$ ./manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/luvpreet/.virtualenvs/mongo3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/luvpreet/.virtualenvs/mongo3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 302, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/luvpreet/.virtualenvs/mongo3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/luvpreet/.virtualenvs/mongo3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/luvpreet/.virtualenvs/mongo3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/luvpreet/Desktop/drf-vogo/new_mongo/new_mongo/settings.py", line 134, in <module>
    mongoengine.connect(
NameError: name 'mongoengine' is not defined
```

Comment: did you figure it out now? if so please share the solution with us

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET\_KEY setting must not be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128540/django-improperlyconfigured-the-secret-key-setting-must-not-be-empty)