# Working Django site breaks when deploying with Zappa

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, zappa

I have a working Django site that hosts locally without errors, however deploying it with Zappa gives me the following error:

```
The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

Initially while getting setup with Django this error was caused by incorrectly pathed settings, but that was fixed and the SECRET_KEY is present in a base.py file.

One suggestion from the zappa output is to try turning "slim_handler" to false. Doing that results in the following error instead:

```
No module named django.core.wsgi
```

This is another error I had experienced before, when getting the site setup locally. It meant that Django was not present in the virtualenv I had setup (I checked, and the correct version is present now).

What might be the reason that a Django site would work fine when hosted locally, but would give errors (seemingly pathing related) when attempting to deploy with Zappa?

Comment: Probably theres a problem realated with a circular dependency in your django project. Take a look to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128540/django-improperlyconfigured-the-secret-key-setting-must-not-be-empty 
Are your aws keys and secret in place ?

Comment: @marcocarranza Yes I saw that one too. It seems unlikely however, as the 'python manage.py runserver' script runs just fine locally. It's only when deploying with Zappa that I run into the error.

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv with your project? I had alot of issues with Zappa when the name of the proyect is the same as the name of the virtualenv. Renaming the env makes it work.

Comment: @marcocarranza Yes I am using a venv with a unique name. I'm thinking that Zappa's lambda environment is either defaulting to some incorrect versions of dependencies, or perhaps its unable to find its dependencies entirely

Comment: Other thing you can test is to downgrade the Zappa version. I had some issues with version 0.48.x so i fall back to 0.47.1

Comment: I'm also noticing that during the 'downloading and installing dependencies' phase of the deployment, zappa gives me some warnings about how it is using 'precompiled lambda package versions' instead of the ones I specified. Possibly related?

Comment: Can you check if your python version is supported by Lambda? Also you need to change the slim handler setting to True, Django projects have a lot of dependencies

Comment: Right, which gives me the wsgi error mentioned in the OP. Any thoughts on what that might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being (probably) that I was using Django 1.9.x when Zappa requires 1.10+