# Error: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty

Tags: django, python-3.6

I am currently attempting to update django from 1.4 to 2.0 after many syntax corrections I have run into this error when trying to run the server. I am updating django by having installed the latest version on my previous directory.

From everything that ive read online, the `SECRET_KEY` should be set in the `settings.py` which it is in my case.

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.

Here is a snippet of where I am defining the SECRET_KEY variable as well as commented out attempts of what I have tried in my settings.py:

```html
# Examples: "http://foo.com/media/", "/media/".

if versionNumber >= 1.3 and revisionNumber >= 3.1:
        STATIC_URL = '/media/'
else:
        ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'


# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
#print ('before the SECRET KEY is defined')
#SECRET_KEY=os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY", 'tk1@!52kv9m(1hf5*t$q6e0am&1yon*-hlet0a+m975zg9a0)c')
SECRET_KEY='tk1@!52kv9m(1hf5*t$q6e0am&1yon*-hlet0a+m975zg9a0)c'
#print ('after the secret key is defined ',SECRET_KEY)


# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
        (
                'django.template.loaders.cached.Loader',
```

If anyone has any resolutions please let me know as I have been struggling with this error for a couple of days now. I understand this may be an issue in the way I am updating so if anyone has more in depth information on updating django that would be very helpful as well.

Comment: Please post a snippet from your settings.py.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET\_KEY setting must not be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128540/django-improperlyconfigured-the-secret-key-setting-must-not-be-empty)