# getting error : django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty in django

Tags: python, django

When i try to run `django`, i am getting error `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty` , there is already SECRET_KEY exist in settings.py file  `SECRET_KEY = 'g1tmo148kxtw#^obw&apoms%n=&4g+2qi1ssuc$v3(fig-he4u'` still i am getting the error, can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue ?

settings.py

```
import django
django.setup()

import os


# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'g1tmo148kxtw#^obw&apoms%n=&4g+2qi1ssuc$v3(fig-he4u'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128540/django-improperlyconfigured-the-secret-key-setting-must-not-be-empty

Comment: Are you using different settings for your project? or somehow **importing** your `SECRET_KEY` from somewhere?

Comment: I dont't know, i am new in python

Comment: Show us your `settings.py` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `django.setup()` on your `setting.py` file and you're good to go.

To clarify it more, when `django.setup()` is called, it should already have a settings file, and therefore a `SECRET_KEY`; So it raise such an error.

Comment: If i removed it then getting this error : django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

Comment: You should include the list of your `INSTALLED_APPS` in the settings file, I think that's the cause of problem. btw why you're not using the django's default setting template?

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    #'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'trialrisk',
] this app is already in settings.py file

Comment: I think the problem is about `django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey`. Try removing it; Because you can't load a **field** from `django.contrib.contenttypes` as the `django.contrib.contenttypes` itself hasn't fully loaded.

Comment: I removed it and getting this error : ImportError: cannot import name 'generics'

Comment: Use this: `INSTALLED_APPS = [ 'django.contrib.admin', 'django.contrib.auth', 'django.contrib.contenttypes', 'django.contrib.sessions', 'django.contrib.messages', 'django.contrib.staticfiles', 'trialrisk', ]`; namely: remove `django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey` and uncomment `django.contrib.contenttypes`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203305/discussion-between-nikul-panchal-and-pedram-parsian).