# Django SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty with github workflow

Tags: python, django, github-actions

I have a GitHub workflow for Django and when it gets to migrating the database it gives the error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

the secret key is stored in a `.env` file and loaded with

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
from pathlib import Path
env_path = Path('.') / '.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("secret_key")
```

Here is the file tree

```
C:.
|   db.sqlite3
|   manage.py
|
\---djangosite
    |   .env
    |   asgi.py
    |   settings.py
    |   urls.py
    |   wsgi.py
    |   __init__.py
    |
    \---__pycache__
        ...
```

This is the manage.py, it is the regular django one with the load .env code from settings.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
from pathlib import Path
env_path = Path('.') / '.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'djangosite.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

when I run `manage.py` on my PC it loads the key and runs the server, but GitHub gives the error above. 
How do I stop this error from happening?

Comment: You sure the problem is not to do with your `.gitignore`?

Comment: what do you mean @AzyCrw4282

Comment: Did you include your `.env` file in the `.gitignore` file?

Comment: no, the .env is in GitHub and has a key

Comment: Can you update your `file hierarchy` as well as your `manage.py`?

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 I've added the file tree and the manage.py code

Comment: You say this error is occurring in GitHub actions, so it doesn't really matter what the project looks like on your PC. Can you show the same hierarchy on GitHub, as well as what your workflow file looks like (atleast the step/job that calls `manage.py`)

Comment: @smac89 the file hierarchy on GitHub is the same as my PC, the only difference is some a `.vscode` directory
and the workflow is to run `python manage.py test`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have stored the `SECRET_KEY` in your system's environment variable, then for GitHub workflow, you can add a *dummy* environment variable in the YAML file.

The **settings.py** should look like this

```py
import os
...
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') # Or the name by which you stored environment variable
...
```

The steps are given below:

**Step 1:** Generate a dummy `SECRET_KEY`. You can create it yourself by

```py
import secrets
print(secrets.token_hex(25))
```

Or generate from a site like [this](https://djecrety.ir/).

**Step 2:** In your .github/workflows YAML file (e.g., django.yml), add this

```yaml
steps:
...
- name: Run Tests
  env: 
    SECRET_KEY: your-genereated-secret_key
  run: |
    python manage.py test
```

Then everything will work fine with the same version of code in your local environment, production environment, and GitHub workflow.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @PhysicistSouravDas's answer. You can alternatively do:

```
- name: Run Tests
    env:
    SECRET_KEY: ${{ secrets.SECRET_KEY }}
    run: |
        python manage.py test
```

Now, go to the **settings** of your **GitHub repository**. Under the **secrets** menu, click **Actions** and then click **New Repository Secret**.

Add a new secret with the name **SECRET_KEY** and value as the dummy SECRET_KEY generated by the method suggested by @PhysicistSouravDas.

GitHub Actions would pick up the SECRET_KEY from there.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `python manage.py runserver 8000` you are using `manage.py` which is settings your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to `settings`. It doesn't appear that you have a `settings.py` in your root directory, so this line in `manage.py`:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")
```

should become:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Your-App-Name.settings")
```

as you have in your `wsgi.py` file.

You can also check here for some other possible [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20646241/2532070).

Comment: I've just added the file tree, the settings.py exists and i can run the server on my PC without errors

Comment: Have you tried the solution in the answer and have a look at the solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20646241/2532070 . this can be happening for myriad of reasons so you will have to do some trial and error to fix the issue

Comment: In the worse case, you can simply set a value to your secret key in `settings.py` on Github and that should solve it (of-course).

Comment: I have done what you said and set a value and in settings.py (KEY) then I changed the readme (its a public project) to say to replace the key in settings.py