# Django: ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty

Tags: django, docker, environment-variables, settings, secret-key

I've seen other posts about this such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128540/django-improperlyconfigured-the-secret-key-setting-must-not-be-empty?answertab=modifieddesc#tab-top) but I still can't figure out my issue.

File structure of relevant files:

```
ba_django_project
|  docker-compose.prod.yml
|
|__app
   |  Dockerfile.prod
   |  manage.py
   |  .env.prod
   |
   |__ba_django_project
      |  __init__.py
      |  settings.py
      |  wsgi.py
```

docker-compose.prod.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    image: 370950449536.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ba_django_project:ba_django_project_web
    command: gunicorn ba_django_project.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ./app/.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:13.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./app/.env.prod.db
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    image: 370950449536.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ba_django_project:ba_django_project_nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    ports:
      - 1337:80
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
from decouple import config
import os


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = int(os.environ.get("DEBUG", default=0))

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'ec2-3-20-22-254.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com', '0.0.0.0', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1'
]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'crispy_forms',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'resume.apps.ResumeConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

# etc. can post full version if needed
```

.env.prod:

```
SECRET_KEY='secretkeyfiller'
```

manage.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'ba_django_project.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'ba_django_project.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I wasn't getting this error before I started trying to get the app to run on a server. Only possible solutions it seems are either I messed up something with `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` or there's some sort or circular dependency I can't find. I've looked through all my files to try to find files importing settings and I took out their references to settings and it still won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You must have messed up with your SECRET_KEY while you were trying to secure it using `.env`.
You must have an actual secret key. E.g: `SECRET_KEY=QhJgFHhvNJFFHjFfdH....`in the`.env` file. If you don't have it, there are ways to generate it using this [guide](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-generate-a-django-secretkey)

> NOTE: no quotes around the secret key in the `.env` file.

Comment: The one in the post isn't my actual secret key.

Answer (score 0):

Although I could have sworn I double checked this, when I went to echoed my .env file into my server, the special characters in the secret key caused it to skip that line. [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script) can help with inputting special characters using `sed`.

If that wasn't the issue, I also removed the quotes around my secret key.