# how to insert in syspath before debugging in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I wish for a specific module to be inserted at the head of the syspath before I debug a file so that this module is picked up instead of a different version of the module in a release location.

e.g. run this code after I click the Debug button in PyCharm:

```
import sys; sys.path.insert(0, "/my/local/path")
```

does anybody know how to do this in PyCharm?

at the moment I'm copying in this line of code at the top of the file I am debugging but this is messy and I shouldn't be messing with live code like that in case i make a commit by mistake.

Comment: This method is actually not solving my problem...
I wish to be able to set breakpoints in this other file that the initial file is calling and catch those breakpoints when debugging.

However, at the moment it is skipping this other file and it's breakpoints calling the pyc of the file instead.... any ideas folks? thanks

Comment: I would still like to know the answer for the original question btw!

Answer (score 0):

+1 to your question. And I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15282950/707580.

1. use `virtualenvwrapper`
2. run `(yourvenv)$ add2virtualenv /my/local/path`

If you know about `virtualenv`, I think the above bullets are straight forward. If not, leave me a comment and I will try to elaborate what's useful.