# Deal with several package versions in python virtualenv

Tags: python, numpy, virtualenv

I'm using a computation server where I have no root privileges, so in order to be able to install whatever libraries I want, I created a `virtualenv` with `--system-site-packages` for python 2.6.

Then, inside the virtual environment, I installed numpy version 1.8.2 because the system numpy version (1.3.0) is too old for my requirements:

> numpy           - 1.3.0        - active development (/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages)
>
> numpy           - 1.8.2        - non-active

I need the `--system-site-packages` option because I'm using some system libraries that I cannot install in the virtual environment. However I am not able to tell the virtual environment to use the most recent version of numpy.

Does anyone know how to select version 1.8.2 in the virtual environment? I tried with `pkg_resources.require('numpy==1.8.2')` but I got the error:

> `pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (numpy 1.3.0 (/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('numpy==1.8.2'))`

Is there some way of telling the virtual environment to look for libraries in the virtual `virt2/lib64/python2.6/site-packages` folder before looking in the system's `/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages` folder?

Comment: Possible using pip, I am not sure about pkg_resources, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079607/make-virtualenv-inherit-specific-packages-from-your-global-site-packages

Comment: How exactly did you install numpy inside your virtualenv? You should just be able to `~$ pip install -I numpy==1.8.2` (the `-I` might be needed in order to tell `pip` to ignore the system-wide numpy that's already installed). What output do you get when you call `~$ python -c "import numpy; print numpy.__version__, numpy.__file__"` from within your virtualenv?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that ou have been bitten by [issue #461](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/461) and currently(as of August-2014) you CANNOT upgrade any system-inherited package because `virtualenv`'s paths are ordered AFTER any system-paths within `sys.path`.

Your workaround it to move the (usually) last sys-path entry one position above:

- Re-ordering `sys.path` with python-code., For instance, assuming that the index of your virtualenv's `site-packages` is the last one, you have to make sure that the following code runs before any other code:

  ```
  import sys; sys.path.insert(0, sys.path.pop(-1))
  ```
- modify similarly your [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment-variable before executing python-interpreter (see [question #10738919](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10738919) and ).