# Matplotlib in virtualenv for Python3

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, linux-mint

I installed matplotlib with package manager in Linux Mint 17.1. When I type import matplotlib in python3 terminal, everything works fine. However, when I create virtualenv, and then I run this command, Python cannot find this module. Can I somehow force my virtual environment to see it is already installed?

Comment: It sounds like you need to [add the matplotlib directory to the virtualenv's `sys.path`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10738919/190597).

Comment: Should I do this in main script via sys.path.extend or there is some better way?

Comment: Sounds like you created a virtualenv with `--no-site-packages`, if it is the case you need to install matplotlib again, this time for your virtualenv instead of the system, you can do that using `pip install -U matplotlib`

Comment: I did not use this flag. That is exactly what I was thinking, virtualenv should still see automatically path to matplotlib installed via linux package manager. I don't want to use pip, especially I tried this and had many problems with launching the graph.