# Create .pth file in virtual environment to make my package importable without using pip or import-utils

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda

I've created a virtual environment using

```
conda create --name py
```

And my initial plan was to add a directory to the `PYTHONPATH` variable but only for the `py` virtual environment.

I since found an alternative solution that uses [.pth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738919/how-do-i-add-a-path-to-pythonpath-in-virtualenv) files. I've followed the instructions and put the file containing my package into an plain text file with a `.pth` extension and saved into the `site-packages` directory for the `py` environment but this does not allow my to `import` my package.

In summary: I put this path

```
`C:\Users\Ciaran\Documents\PyCoTools`
```

which contains the `setup.py` for my package into a plain text file and saved to

```
C:\Anaconda2\envs\pycotools\Lib\site-packages\pycotools.pth
```

However I still cannot import my package from anywhere other than the package directory. Can anybody point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can automatically set environment variables when the environment is activated. See: https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html#windows

Answer (score 0):

From the commands and paths you have described, I would say, that you put the pth file in the site-packages directory of a wrong virtual environment: in conda params you named your VE as py, but the pth file is stored in VE for pycotools.

The pth file should be available to the python interpreter with which you run your script. The interpreter scans its site-packages directory and adds the paths from the pth files to its sys.path. That is you can inspect whether your path is added by printing the contents of sys.path.

Another thing that comes to my mind is that a directory where your setup.py is located is not relevant if the module itself is located somewhere else. The pth file just allows you to patch your sys.path, not to install your package. If the package requires installation, you should better install it in your specially created VE.