# “has no attribute 'reduce_cython” error when using Pyinstaller exe

Tags: python-3.x, cython, pyinstaller, spacy

I used pyinstaller to convert my Python file to exe. While executing it I got the below error,

> AttributeError: type object 'neuralcoref.neuralcoref.array' has no
>   attribute '**reduce_cython**' I'm using Python 3.6.7, Pyinstaller 4.0,
>   NeuralCoref 4, Spacy 2.1.0, Cython 0.27.3.

Any suggestion to solve this or better way to convert .py to exe? I've tried py2exe, Cxfreee but doesnt work.

A minimal version of my code:

```
import neuralcoref
def ApplyCorefResolutionToPreProcessedMail(text, nlp):
    # load NeuralCoref and add it to the pipe of SpaCy's model
    coref = neuralcoref.NeuralCoref(nlp.vocab) 
    nlp.add_pipe(coref, name='neuralcoref')
    doc = nlp(text)
    corefresolvedmail = doc._.coref_resolved
    return corefresolvedmail
```

I have attached the stack trace below,
[image]

Comment: Give us a minimal version of your code.

Comment: hi @M.R. I have add the minimal version of the code in the question

Comment: Does this link help you ? https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1953

Comment: How you call the function (add it to the code), also do you have the error when you run the script directly?

Comment: The script works fine when run directly. But the executable generated by Pyinstaller throws the specified error.

Answer (score 1):

This might be resolved in cython 0.28 look here https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1953

Comment: I'd imagine it isn't that you need Cython 0.28, but that you need NeuralCoref built with Cython 0.28

Comment: @DavidW Correct. I just need NeuralCoref. And the requirements for Neural are ,
spacy>=2.1.0
cython>=0.25
pytest

Comment: What if you compile neuralcoref from source with Cython 0.28 ?

Comment: see here for compiling neuralcoref from source: https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref#install-neuralcoref-from-source

Comment: thanks @SofieVL. Tried that as well. Does not work.