# Error running tkinter executable with cx_freeze

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, nltk, cython, cx-freeze

Im creating a executable for my tkinter app, after the build is complete and i click on the exe file i get the following message.

AtrributeError:Type object 'scipy.sparse.csgrap._shortest_path.array' has no attribute '**reduce_cython**'

Python: **3.7.3**
Cython: **0.29.6**

Setup.py

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os.path
import sys


PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))


base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"
executables = [Executable("index.py", base=base)]

include_files = [os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'),
         os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll')]
packages = [ "pandas", "ibm_watson", "datetime","sqlalchemy","json","simplejson","nltk"]
options = {
    'build_exe': {    
        'packages':packages,
        'include_files': include_files
    },    
}

setup(
    name = "Carrefour Nlc",
    options = options,
    version = "0.0.1",
    description = '<any description>',
    executables = executables
)
```

**Traceback**

[image: Error Traceback]

I have no idea how to fix this , i apreciate any help.

Comment: i guess is more related to cx_freeze than anything, the program is running fine is only the builded version who gives me this error

Comment: Please remove the `tkinter` tag and pick one from [`[python] scipy cx-freeze`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D+scipy+cx-freeze)

Comment: maybe someone who made a executable version of a tkinter app could help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: type object 'pandana.cyaccess.cyaccess' has no attribute '\_\_reduce\_cython\_\_'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58275685/attributeerror-type-object-pandana-cyaccess-cyaccess-has-no-attribute-redu)

Comment: Also a similar error: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57175603/5769463

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, i tried to upgrade my cython as indicated in the first link but didnt work out

Comment: @WallaceSilva You'll need to have a version of Scipy built with a recent version of Cython (since the error looks to be in Scipy rather than your code). That probably means upgrading Scipy, but you could try rebuilding it yourself if you're feeling brave

Comment: hey @DavidW i dont feel brave at all ! hahah how can i find a version of scipy build with same cython version?

Comment: @WallaceSilva I don't know. I'd try forcing Anaconda to update it first

Comment: @DavidW i was able to solve.. i deleted all dependencies of the project in my conda env and download one by one, i guess i was having some conflict issues of dependencies between my env and the project.

Comment: Glad you got it working - the nice thing about conda is that it's very easy to create new environments to try different setups. This is unfortunately the kind of problem that's hard to solve remotely