# Python tests run locally on ubuntu but fails when run through Jenkins with error "ImportError while importing test module '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace"

Tags: python, jenkins

Jenkins setup is on Ubuntu.

Local: Created a virtual environment using python 3.6, running tests through command line using pythom -m pytest - ./{test.py} which is successful

Jenkins job:

In the Build > Shell script, creating a virtual environment the same way done locally and running the commands.

python3.6 -m venv jenkins-venv

source ${WORKSPACE}/jenkins-venv/bin/activate

pip install --no-cache-dir -r ${WORKSPACE}/project/requirements.txt

python -m pytest -v ${WORKSPACE}/project/test_day1.py

Error:
 ERROR collecting scripts/
ImportError while importing test module '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/job_name/project/test_Login.py'.

Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens if your PATH variable includes that module's directory on your machine but not on Jenkins.

Comment: Hi Josh, my Jenkins and user machine are the same. Also, checked the PATH values locally and through Jenkins shell, both does not contain the project modules entry.

Comment: Hey @AkshayJ, I recently was working through this issue with virtual environments as well. I learned that you can add a .pth file to the site-packages directory of your python installation to add a direction to your Python path. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10739838/3801865). This might not actually be your issue, just throwing it out there.

Comment: Issue is resolved:
After creating virtual environment, I just changed the directory to the root (cd ${WORKSPACE}/{project root DIR}) of the project and it started picking up the test scripts.
Thanks for your help. :)